# Displaying rows where condition matches some part of string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

We use

```
fund_data.loc[fund_data['SubVertical']=="Data Analytics platform"]
```

to display all details of the columns containing these('Data Analytics platform') strings in the condition of a column in pandas, but suppose we want to display rows containing even some part of the string like all rows having the word 'Data' in the 'SubVertical' column.

```
fund_data.loc[fund_data['SubVertical']=="%Data%"] #or something like this
```

should return the following

```
  c1 c2
1 A  Data Analysis
2 B  Data Analytics
3 C  Big  Data
4 D  Consumer Data platfrom
5 E  Data platforms
etc....
```

Comment: `fund_data.loc[fund_data['SubVertical'].str.contains('Data')]`

Comment: the code gave the following error `cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` but this did the job `fund_data.loc[fund_data['SubVertical'].str.contains('Data')==True]`

Comment: `fund_data.loc[fund_data['SubVertical'].str.contains('Data', na=False)]`